# Changing bearing in Android Google Maps makes target location drift

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm building an Android app where north points to the true north (rather than up). I'm getting the bearing values to update quite fine using the sensor framework, but when I apply them to the map the target location drifts by a few meters on each application.

```
private void rotateCameraTo(float bearing) {
    CameraPosition current = map.getCameraPosition();
    LatLng lastTarget = current.target;
    CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition(current.target, current.zoom, current.tilt, bearing);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));

    double distance = distanceTo(map.getCameraPosition().target, lastTarget);
    if (distance > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Target moved: " + distance);
    }
}
```

I tried adding:

```
    CameraPosition anotherPosition = new CameraPosition(lastTarget, current.zoom, current.tilt, bearing);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(anotherPosition));
```

where the blank line is but it seemed to make no difference.

I also tried to remember the target position and update it when user moves the map manually, and then set it to such on any update of the map, but it caused the map to become 'sticky' where the user couldn't scroll it manually; in any case it seems a hack.

I'm getting roughly this in logs as output (distanceTo returns Haversine formula result in meters):

```
06-10 05:13:24.905    D/MapsFragment﹕ Target moved: 10.573359329046834
06-10 05:13:24.925    D/MapsFragment﹕ Target moved: 10.573379953568864
06-10 05:13:24.925    D/MapsFragment﹕ Target moved: 10.580972456831576
```

This seems to be some floating point loss of precision issue, but since it appears to happen in Google Maps code I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas what's the best way to just do a bearing change (rotation) on a map without affecting anything else?

Alternatively, is there another way to implement a map that changes its orientation to always point north besides what I'm doing?

Comment: I also faced this issue. Did you find the solution?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't recall having solved this. Please post here if you find a solution.

Comment: Its been a long while (now end March 2016) since this was asked. I'm seeing the same drift.  Anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by storing the target LatLng in an attribute. When the heading was changed, instead of retrieving the target from the *CameraPosition* I used the stored target. This way the map doesn't drift anymore.

As I also track the location while rotating the map by the heading, this stored target has to be updated when a new location is notified.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with example